# Overlapping strings

Tags: c++, c, string, char, arduino

I have a problem with overlapping char*.

I'm working in a low-memory environment, namely Arduino and I would like to use the least memory possible. I want to be able to prepend a string with another and to do it without any copying of variables which wastes memory.

This is standard C or C++.

```
char* bigPacket = (char*)malloc(25);   //Makes a big string of length 25
char* payload = bigPacket + 2;         //This is part of the big string, 2 chars in.
bigPacket[0] = 72;                     // Letter 'H'
bigPacket[1] = 72;                     //I'm expecting the final bigPacket to read    "HHHello, world"
payload = "Hello, World";
print(bigPacket);
```

But the problem is that it does not print "HHHello, world" as it should. Instead, it just prints "HH". Is there a proper way to make it be able to overlap these strings to print "HHHello, world"?

Comment: Are you familiar with `strcpy`?

Comment: You point a pointer to some string literal and expect that to copy the string literal? strcpy, memcpy or the like are needed here.

Comment: The line `payload = ..` is *not* "standard C", and only standard C++ if `payload` is a `cstring`.

Comment: @Jongware: How is it not standard C (though not what was intended)? (Anyway, it certainly is not standard C++).

Comment: @Jongware There's no `cstring` in standard C++. `std::string` would work though.

Comment: @Dedup: well, I suppose you're right, it *is* valid. It certainly is not my own standard. Alan: yeah last time I seriously tried C++ it was with Borland's CBuilder (sp.?).

Comment: It seems like you just don't understand what this line of code does: `payload = "Hello, World";`. Once you understand what that does, it should be obvious how to write code that does what you expected that line of code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed where `payload` points. What you needed to do was leave `payload` alone and change the data it points to.

```
strcpy(payload, "Hello World");
```

Edit: If you really want to avoid copies you'd end up with something like the SGI Rope class. But you'd pay a lot in code complexity.

Comment: Alright, thanks. The only problem now is that whenever I try to print the bigPacket variable, it only prints the part that is part of bigPacket but NOT the part that says "Hello World" Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: My answer was the solution. Did you try it?

Comment: Ah Yes. Now, I tried it with a payload that is originally defined, but when I add characters to prepend it, it becomes gibberish. Any ideas? Thanks realy appreciate it!.

Comment: That sounds like another question. And you'll need to provide more detail. (Do you understand why it works with `strcpy` and not without?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without either very complicated code or multiple copies of data, destroying the benefit, you need to have the complete string as one literal in your program: "HHHelloWorld". You can then play with pointers and lengths to access various parts of it, but remember there is only one null byte, at the end of the string.

However, I suspect that this is an over-optimization. Arduino programming rarely involves a lot of very long string. It is important to keep the code simple and direct.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mess with pointers for something like that. Instead you should store string literals in flash instead of sram memory. This is usually done with the help of [progmem macros.](http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/PROGMEM) Often the ["F" macro](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Memory) is sufficient though. Then you can copy your strings - as needed - and if needed - into a suitable buffer.

Simplest example:

```
Serial.println(F("this is text from flash memory"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You just assign the `payload` pointer to point to the constant string, you do not copy the string to what it currently points to.

In order to copy the string you need to use strcpy or memcpy:

```
char *bigPacket = malloc(25);
bigPacket[0] = bigpacket[1] = 72;

strcpy( bigpacket+2, "Hello, World");

print( bigPacket );
```

Note that this is rather unlikely to save memory, since "Hello, world" will exist as a constant string in your code, to save memory it is probably most efficient to call print multiple times.

However, I guess that is not possible in this case.

Comment: Depending on the chip used though, the string literal might be stored in the NVRAM or flash, as opposed to the limited 1k of stack space. It might help.

Comment: Well, the whole point was that there is no need to ever use malloc at all as the example was formulated, just call print several times (print sends data to the serial port, the extra delay that is introduced by calling it multiple times is highly unlikely to matter, and it would save up to 32 bytes of RAM in this case)